# How to identify the active instance of a form when clicking on its menustrip component

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I am building a kind of prototype for a MDI application. I have a main form, called mainForm, and some other child forms, all instances of a childForm class. These instances of my childForm class have all a basic MenuStrip, with some form\close, print, etc toolStripMenuItems.

At click time, how can I identify which instance of the childForm class is holding the activated toolStripMenuItem?

EDIT: following dash comment

The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
Form myNewForm = new Form()
MenuStrip myNewMenu = new MenuStrip()
...
myNewForm.Controls.Add(myNewMenu)
myNewForm.MainMenuStrip = myNewMenu
```

Comment: You could try looking at the parent property. If that's a control, then look at its parent, and so on, until you reach the first form - that should be the form hosting your control. There is also the FindForm method  on the control too - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform

Comment: I have been manipulating these Parents, findForms and other methods and properties without any success. My ToolStripMenuItem Parent is a ToolStripDropDownMenu, whose Parent and/or FindForm return null ...

Comment: How are you adding the MenuStrip to the instance of the ChildForm? Is it done at design time, and then, at runtime, you just create an instance of that form? Or do you add the MenuStrip at runtime too? Is it the same MenuStrip or does each form have it's own instance?

Comment: each instance of a form has its own menu strip added at instanciation time. Please see update in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my original comment, and your update, the following works for me:

```
  Form newChildForm = new Form();
  newChildForm.Name = "ChildForm";
  MenuStrip newMenu = new MenuStrip();

  ToolStripItem newItem = newMenu.Items.Add("New Item");
  newItem.Click += new EventHandler(newItem_Click);

  newChildForm.Controls.Add(newMenu);
  newChildForm.MainMenuStrip = newMenu;

  newChildForm.Show();
```

Then, in the event handler:

```
void newItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ToolStripItem clickedItem = sender as ToolStripItem;

  MenuStrip parentMenu = clickedItem.Owner as MenuStrip;

  Form childForm = parentMenu.FindForm() as Form;
  //childForm.Parent is also "ChildForm";

}
```

Are you doing anything differently?

Comment: The click event was added to the MyMenuItem:ToolStripMenuItem object when while building the MyMenuItem instance, so the event was managed at the MyMenuItem class level. Here you are proposing to add the event manager at the form level ... which does make the job ... Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to dash, that should have been posted as an answer.

Im going to assume that you are inside the click event of the menu item...

```
Control s = sender as Control;//the sender object from the click event
ChildForm activeForm = s.FindForm() as ChildForm;
```

This would give the specific instance of the form you are looking for.

alternatively, the button click event SHOULD be implemented from the ChildForm class itself, which would mean that during any click event, your "this" operator should in fact BE the specific instance of The ChildForm class being activated.

```
ChildForm activeForm = this;
```

which is an entirely unnecessary assignment but does illustrate the point.  This would not be true if your menu strip was located on some other custom user control container, in which case you would need something like this.

```
ChildForm activeForm = this.ParentForm;
```

the ParentForm property is unique to 'ContainerControl' which is defined as a control which can contain other controls, and it identifies the base 'form' on which the container is being displayed.

Comment: I gave it a try, and I am getting an error. When debugging the code, I am checking the following: ?((Control)sender).ToString(), and getting the message: Cannot cast 'sender' (which has an actual type of 'MonApp.FenetreApplication.ItemMenu') to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' (where ItemMenu is my own class derivating from ToolStripMenuItem)

Comment: I was using Control as a generic.  MenuItems might not be controls themselves, but you should be able to identify the menu it belongs to, which is a control.

what class is the menu item's on_click event itself defined?  Is it part of the ChildForm, Part of the MainForm, or somewhere else entirely?